# Does AI in video games change algorithms by modifying parameters or choose one among a set of algorithms?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm new to AI and have doubts about it in video games. It's hard for me to get the mechanism of its learning. Do computer engines in video games make new algorithms by just changing weights based on inputs (an algorithm is new if it has new weights) or they completely decide a specific algorithm with a certain set of inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Well, 99% of game AI isnt a neural network, its just a "normal AI" , well, of course you can have very complex AI tehniques wich adapt to the player, but you wouldnt (most probably) see machine learning into it